# Express + NextJS, cookie not stored in browser

Tags: express, http, next.js, cookies

I use expressjs and nextjs for my app, and I'm struggling to figure  out what is the problem, in localhost it works, but when I trying with  localtunnel or ngrok it doesn't.
My cookie is sent like this :

```
res.cookie("accessToken", token, {
          maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
          expires: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
          httpOnly: false,
          domain: ".loca.lt",
});
```

I checked the network tab and the cookie is sent by the server in  "Response cookie", but not stored when checking in Storage ->  Cookies.
When I make a client side request from my app to my server the  cookie is successfully passed (even if cookie not visible in browser). But it  is not accessible via a server component.

```
export default function Page() {
    console.log(cookies()) // No cookies
}
```

Update : In Chromium the cookie is stored and visible under Application -> Storage, but still not accessible via server component.

Comment: The `expires` field is supposed to be a date.

Comment: @GuyIncognito You're right, but it doesn't solve the problem.